# What is the AudioMoth absolute sensitivity in V/Pa?

Tags: measurement, hardware, audiomoth

How can I know the absolute sensitivity in V/Pa of AudioMoths (when used alone and also when used in the manufacturer's case) and its relation to the gain setting? A value measured at 1kHz or a full frequency response would be very useful.

I could't find the information on the manufacturers datasheet. In the AudioMoth Dev datasheet, I found the sensitivity of the MEM mic and the pre-amplifier gain but I'm not sure this applies for the regular AudioMoth.

I also found this very good work that tested all gain settings but it only gives relative levels between them: https://github.com/kitzeslab/audiomoth-performance/blob/main/report.md

Any other ressources?

Answer (score 8):

There [is a comprehensive experiment](https://github.com/kitzeslab/audiomoth-performance) looking at the *relative* frequency dependent sensitivity of the AudioMoth in different housings, however, I have never been able to find a reference where the absolute sensitivity of an AudioMoth has been determined. The MEMS microphone will have that info in the datasheet but that should not be relied on for the overall sensitivity of the system and it does not cover most of the relevant frequency spectrum.

Answer (score 6):

Someone asked a similar question in the openacoustics forum. See here:
https://www.openacousticdevices.info/support/configuration-support/audio-moth-sensitivity

Apparently the different Audiomoth Versions use different MEMS microphones. AudioMoth 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 use the SPM0408LE5H - see datasheet [here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Knowles%20Acoustics%20PDFs/SPM0408LE5H-TB.pdf)

AudioMoth 1.2.0 uses the SPU0410LR5H - see datasheet [here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Knowles%20Acoustics%20PDFs/SPU0410LR5H-QB_RevH_3-27-13.pdf)

The sensitivity of the 1.1 is given with a typical value of -18 dBV/Pa and the sensitivity of the 1.2 is given with a typical value of -38 dBV/Pa. Both sensitivities are given for a reference condition of 94 dB SPL @ 1 kHz.  The linked datasheets also contain frequency response curves (normalized to 1 kHz) from 100 Hz to 10 kHz.

Comment: Hi @Fritjof, the sensitivity seems to be missing in the statement '...have a sensitivity of ...'  (only the reference SPL and frequency are given) - could you please fill it in?

Comment: Hi @Thejasvi Thanks for the heads-up. I have edited the answer.

Comment: It should be noted that calibration values up to 10kHz do not cover many of the typical target species the AudioMoth is used to monitor. Thus, these MEMS calibration values are not particularly useful. We really need a calibration values which are well over 100kHz to cover most bat species(e.g. Lesser horsehoe bat in the UK (Rhinolophus hipposideros)).